# .NET Core console application doesn't see environment variable

Tags: .net-core

I want to read environment variable in my .NET Core application but the behavior is strange.

I have added new variable `APP_1=1` and then code to read it `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APP_1")`. When I run it it returns 1.

Then I have added new variable `APP_2=2` and changed code to get `APP_2`. And then it returns null. When I run console echo %APP_2% it works fine and print 2. After logging out and logging if I run my application it works fine and return 2.

It looks like there is some run-time that keeps values from first run. Do you know what to do to fix that?

Comment: How are you starting it? The environment variables are usually read in by the shell, so restarting or resourcing the shell should work.

Comment: I just click run in Visual Studio

Comment: Have you tried restarting Visual Studio? If you open up a command prompt and run the executable, it should pick up on the new environment variables.

Comment: That helps, but is there something smaller that I could restart?

Comment: You have to reload the environment variables. I am not sure if Visual Studio gives you a way to do that. You can always just start the executable and then attach the debugger. Why are you changing environment variables this way? Maybe you are better off with a different storage mechanism?